# creating receivers for logs and pipeline for new receivers

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-ops-agent

In Google Cloud Ops Agent, an example of MySQL config.yaml is given as:

```
logging:
  receivers:
    mysql_error:
      type: mysql_error
    mysql_general:
      type: mysql_general
    mysql_slow:
      type: mysql_slow
  service:
    pipelines:
      mysql:
        receivers:
          - mysql_error
          - mysql_general
          - mysql_slow
metrics:
  receivers:
    mysql:
      type: mysql
  service:
    pipelines:
      mysql:
        receivers:
          - mysql
```

And to ingest logs from MySQL, **receivers must be created for MySQL logs** and **a pipeline created for the new receivers**.

How would you go about including:

include_paths

as

"**type**"

and

/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

as

"**value**"?

I've been unable to find a good documentation covering this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file` as the **type** and the `path` you specified in your post as the **value**. Below is a sample code for your use case:

```
receivers:
  RECEIVER_ID:
    type: files

    include_paths: [/var/log/*.log]
    exclude_paths: [/var/log/not-this-one.log]
```

For more information about this topic you can visit it on the [Official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#logging-receivers).

Comment: That was exactly the documentation I was looking for. Thanks, Alex.